# Entity framework one direction one to many cascade deleting

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, cascading-deletes

I have two entities:

```
public class Report : SimpleEntity
{
     public virtual ICollection<BaseFrequency> Frequencies
    {
        get
        {
            return _requencies ?? (_requencies = new HashSet<BaseFrequency>());
        }

        set
        {
            _requencies = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CustomReport : SimpleEntity
{
   public virtual string Name {get; set;}

   public Report Report { get; set; } 
}
```

Mappings:

```
internal class BaseFrequency: EntityMappingBase<BaseFrequency>
    {
        public BaseFrequency()
        {
            Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(250).IsRequired(); 
        }
    }

internal class MyReportMapping : EntityMappingBase<MyReport>
{
    public MyReportMapping()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Frequencies).WithOptional(x => x.Report).HasForeignKey(x => x.ReportId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);         
    }
}
```

When I delete Report I get "

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   \"Report_Frequencies\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"SamAssist\", table \"dbo.BaseFrequencies\", column
>   'ReportId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."} error  The DELETE
>   statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   \"Report_Frequencies\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"SamAssist\", table \"dbo.BaseFrequencies\", column
>   'ReportId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated

And DB restrictions is [image]

What should I do to fix this bug?